# same LINQ queries but different tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

```
await _context.TableA
                .Where(x => request.A == null || x.A == request.A)
                .Where(x => request.StartDate == null || x.CreatedAt >= request.StartDate)
                .Where(x => request.EndDate == null || x.CreatedAt <= request.EndDate)
                .GroupBy(g => new { g.A, g.B, g.C } )
                .Select(g => new dtoA
                {
                    A = g.Key.A,
                    B = g.Key.B,
                    C = g.C
                })
                .ToListAsync();
```

**And i have same request but to another table**

```
await _context.TableB
                .Where(x => request.A == null || x.A == request.A)
                .Where(x => request.StartDate == null || x.CreatedAt >= request.StartDate)
                .Where(x => request.EndDate == null || x.CreatedAt <= request.EndDate)
                .GroupBy(g => new { g.A, g.B, g.C } )
                .Select(g => new dtoB
                {
                    A = g.Key.A,
                    B = g.Key.B,
                    C = g.C
                })
                .ToListAsync();
```

**Queries are same but tables are different. So question is, how can i combine queries, or create 1 base query?**

Comment: Fast forward: Just leave them like they are. Do not combine queries, which are independent. You are not joining anything at all, so why would you combine them?

Comment: Everywhere you are using `x.` you are referring to different properties with the same name, so the queries are not the same.

Comment: You can't do it, MAYBE with reflection, but that's no sence. They must be separate. It`s like you have two difference coffe shop in your sity and you want to have similar price, weak example, but still

Comment: You could do this if both of your entities implement the same interface with properties called `A`, `CreatedAt` etc.

Comment: @DavidG, `dtoA`  and `dtoB` ruins this idea.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Not really, they would also need to be passed in as generics and have the same base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this if both of your entities implement the same interface with all relevant properties. Same goes for the DTO classes too. For example:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    string A { get; }
    DateTime CreatedAt { get; }
    // etc
}
```

And each of your entities must implement that:

```
public class TableA : IFoo { ... }
public class TableB : IFoo { ... }
```

The same goes for your DTO classes:

```
public interface IDto
{
    string A { get; set; }
    string B { get; set; }
    string C { get; set; }
    // etc
}
```

Now you can make a generic method that takes generic types and constrains them to be the interfaces created above. Also, use the [`DbSet.Set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.set?view=efcore-6.0) method to get the correct entity type from the context.

```
public async Task<List<TDto>> GetData<TEntity, TDto>(Request request)
    where TEntity : class, IFoo
    where TDto : IDto, new()
{
    return await _context.Set<TEntity>()
        .Where(x => request.A == null || x.A == request.A)
        .Where(x => request.StartDate == null || x.CreatedAt >= request.StartDate)
        .Where(x => request.EndDate == null || x.CreatedAt <= request.EndDate)
        .GroupBy(g => new { g.A, g.B, g.C } )
        .Select(g => new TDto
        {
            A = g.Key.A,
            B = g.Key.B,
            C = g.C
        })
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

Now you call the method like this:

```
var resultA = await GetData<TableA, dtoA>(request);
var resultB = await GetData<TableB, dtoB>(request);
```